# Как Google Sheets разным пользователям отобразить разные данные, если они на одной таблице?

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Есть необходимость, если пользователь заходит на определённую страницу, поставить inputbox/ячейку поиска и отобразить ему результаты в других ячейках.
Но если другой пользователь зашёл, то он увидит результат запроса пользователя 1, который ему не нужен.
Можно ли сделать, используя Google sheets, что б одна таблица одновременно отображалась по-разному для разных пользователей?

Comment: Ваша задача противоречит сути GoogleSheets. Проще всего пользователю будет склонировать весь документ, и в своей версии уже выполнять запросы.

Comment: Метка Excel поставлена неправильно. В Excel скрытие/отображение данных можно осуществить с помощью макросов. Но нужно для Google, где язык программирования другой.